# How do I filter element when adding to a collection using selenium and c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a collection of elements which I'm gathering by using its className

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> displayedStatues;
displayedStatues = Wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(By.ClassName("dropdown-list__item")));
```

I do get correct result but it also includes elements with text blank values. How do I add additional filtering to ignore blank values?

I tried Skip(1) at the end but that does not help

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> displayedStatues;
displayedStatues = Wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(By.ClassName("dropdown-list__item")).Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(By.ClassName("dropdown-list__item")).Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text)));
```